# Comparing graphs using Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the question that I am working on:

> Suppose the function $y(t) = 6t +1$ is a solution to a differential equation. For the initial condtion $y(0) = 1$, is a graph of the tip-to-tail Euler method exactly the same as the graph of the exact solution? Does step size matter?

Well, when using Euler's method, we are calculating an *approximation*, not the exact answer. Thus, we should be making some sort of error. To answer the first question, I don't think that the graph of Euler's method will be exactly the same as the exact solution due to the error we are making. But I'm not sure if step size does matter here... why does it make a difference if I use a step size of $1$ as opposed to $.5$?